# How to share a string array using open mpi

Tags: c, openmpi

I'm new in openmpi and I don't know how to use scatter and gather to send an array of strings to all processors. I would like to divide an array and send it to each processor, but all I can divide are the characters of a single array element. Can anyone help me please?

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "mpi.h"

#define MASTER 0

#define BUF_SIZE 2048
#define CHAR_SIZE 900                                                       
#define CHARS 13                                                            
#define MAX_SIZE 3500                                                    
#define NUMBER_OF_FILES  2                                                   

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int number_of_words = 0;
    int total_rows = 0; 
    int i, j = 0;

    char **words = (char**) calloc(MAX_SIZE, sizeof (char*));

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++) {
        words[i] = (char*) calloc(CHARS, sizeof (char));
    }

    char **local_words = (char**) calloc(MAX_SIZE, sizeof (char*));

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++) {
        local_words[i] = (char*) calloc(CHARS, sizeof (char));
    }

    char **rec_words = (char**) calloc(MAX_SIZE, sizeof (char*));

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++) {
        rec_words[i] = (char*) calloc(CHARS, sizeof (char));
    }

    char str_righe[BUF_SIZE][CHAR_SIZE]; 

    FILE *f = NULL;
    char f_title[10]; 
    char str_nfiles[10]; 

    char delim[10] = {10, 32, 33, 39, 44, 46, 58, 59, 63}; 

    char *ptr;

    int rank;
    int size;
    int message_length;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    for (i = 1; i <= NUMBER_OF_FILES; i++) {
        strcpy(f_title, "f");
        sprintf(str_nfiles, "%d", i);
        strcat(f_title, str_nfiles);
        strcat(f_title, ".txt");

        f = fopen(f_title, "r");
        while (fgets(str_righe[j], BUF_SIZE, f)) {
            str_righe[j][strlen(str_righe[j])] = '\0';
            j++;
        }
        fclose(f);
    }

    total_rows = j;

    for (i = 0; i < total_rows; ++i) {
        ptr = strtok(str_righe[i], delim);

        while (ptr != NULL) {
            strcpy(words[number_of_words], ptr);
            ptr = strtok(NULL, delim);
            number_of_words++;
        }
    }

    message_length = number_of_words / size;

    if (rank == MASTER) {
        for (i = 0; i < number_of_words; i++)
            printf("%s\n", words[i]);
    }

    MPI_Scatter(*words, message_length, MPI_CHAR, *local_words, message_length, MPI_CHAR, MASTER, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    printf("rank %d, fragment: \t%s\n", rank, *local_words);

    MPI_Gather(*local_words, message_length, MPI_CHAR, *rec_words, message_length, MPI_CHAR, MASTER, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if (rank == MASTER) {
        printf("rank %d, gathered: \t%s\n", rank, *rec_words);
    }

    MPI_Finalize();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I expect the output:

```
iMac-di-iMac01:mpi macbook$ mpirun -n 2 main
Good
time
by
antonio
rank 0, fragment:   Good time
rank 1, fragment:   by antonio
rank 0, gathered:   Good time by antonio
```

But the actual output is:

```
iMac-di-iMac01:mpi macbook$ mpirun -n 2 main
Good
time
by
antonio
rank 0, fragment:   Go
rank 1, fragment:   od
rank 0, gathered:   Good
```

Comment: Hey Antonio. Just some advice: you should try to post your variable names in English. To someone who doesn't speak Italian, the code will be much harder to read if variable names are gibberish to them.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I changed the variable names :)

Comment: Not linked to your problem: this line of code is at best useless, at worst buggy: `str_righe[j][strlen(str_righe[j])] = '\0';`

Comment: thanks for letting me know Mathieu

Comment: Are you trying to send characters array or pointers on characters array? Maybe you can try `MPI_Scatter(words, message_length, MPI_CHAR, local_words, message_length, MPI_CHAR, MASTER, MPI_COMM_WORLD);` This will send pointers on words instead of words

Comment: I'm trying to send string arrays. I tried both solutions, but the result is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I never shared the solution to the problem. I do it now:

I created the matrix variable and I sent the one with the scatter. In this way the slaves received the words and not the characters

```
int *matrix = 0;

matrix = malloc(sizeof (int) * n_words);
    j = 1;
    for (i = 0; i <= n_words; i++) {
        matrix[i] = j;
        j++;
    }

n_words_cpu = n_words / (size);
procRow = malloc(sizeof (int) * n_words); // received row will contain p integers

MPI_Scatter(
            /* send_data       = */ matrix,
            /* send_count      = */ n_words_cpu,
            /* send_datatype   = */ MPI_INT,
            /* recv_data       = */ procRow,
            /* recv_count      = */ n_words_cpu,
            /* recv_datatype   = */ MPI_INT,
            /* root            = */ MASTER,
            /* MPI_commuicator = */ MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```